# Different Results with query('s=computer') vs get_posts('s=computer')?

Tags: wp-query, get-posts

I have two different pieces of code and it's returning two different results.

```
$search_query = new WP_Query();
$search_posts = $search_query->query('s=computer'); 
echo count($search_posts);
```

vs.

```
$search_posts = get_posts('s=computer');
echo count($search_posts);
```

What is the reason for the different values?

*(The value provided by the first one is correct. It's the same as the number of posts that I get when I do a regular search in WP. But the first piece of code won't work inside the plugin's php file, it would work only in a template.)*

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

The default arguments for `get_posts()` function include `'numberposts' => 5`.

So if you're querying for a search term that returns more than five (5) results the second query will return a maximum value of `5` unless you pass `'s=computer&numberposts=-1'` as your query string.

The `WP_Query` object doesn't have a `'numberposts'` default, although it is affected by the *"Blog pages show at most"* count in your settings panel. So if you want the total count using the `query()` function, you should override the defaults like this:

```
$search_query->query('s=computer&nopaging=true')
```

Comment: *@goldenapples* - Nice answer!

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It was driving me crazy and all along there was very simple explanation :-)

Comment: *@Dan* - If *@goldenapples* answer solved your problem please remember to select the checkmark for this answer to give him or her the credit they deserve.